# Grid view is not Showing in android nougat while it is showing in android marshmallow

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-gridview

I have Grid view with images with two columns, the grid view is perfectly showing in the android marshmallow while when i try it in android nougat it only showing the progress bar, not even the placeholder is showing in the android nougat. Please tell me, what is the problem with it. How to solve it.
Below is my code

> Here is glide dependency
>   compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0
>   `activity_profile.xml`

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.vijay.newroot.ProfileActivity">
   <ProgressBar
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
       android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
       />
   <GridView
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:numColumns="auto_fit"
       android:gravity="center"
       android:layout_below="@+id/progress_bar"
       android:verticalSpacing="1dp"
       android:horizontalSpacing="1dp"
       android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
       android:id="@+id/profileList">
      </GridView>
      </RelativeLayout>
```

> card_view.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:weightSum="1">
    <ImageView
   android:layout_width="190dp"
   android:layout_height="190dp"
   android:src="@drawable/fb_avatar"
   android:id="@+id/imageId"/>
   </RelativeLayout>
```

> ProfileActivity.java

```
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.app.ProgressDialog;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.media.Image;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager;
    import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
    import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
    import android.widget.GridView;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.widget.ListAdapter;
    import android.widget.ProgressBar;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
     import com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DiskCacheStrategy;
     import com.bumptech.glide.load.resource.drawable.GlideDrawable;
     import com.bumptech.glide.request.RequestListener;
     import com.bumptech.glide.request.target.Target;
     import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseListAdapter;
     import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter;
     import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
     import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
     import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
     import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
     import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
     import com.google.firebase.database.Query;
     import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
     import com.squareup.picasso.Callback;
     import com.squareup.picasso.NetworkPolicy;
     import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

    import java.util.ArrayList;

     public class ProfileActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
     GridView profileGrid;
     DatabaseReference databaseReference;
     FirebaseAuth mAuth;
     String uid;
     FirebaseHelper helper;
     CustomAdapter adapter;
     ProgressBar progressBar;

     @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);
    databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Blog");
    helper=new FirebaseHelper(databaseReference);
    profileGrid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.profileList);
    progressBar= (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);
    mAuth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    adapter=new CustomAdapter(this, helper.retrieve(),helper.fetchKey(),progressBar);

    profileGrid.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter(this,helper.retrieve(),helper.fetchKey(),progressBar));


      }

     }


   class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
   Context c;
ArrayList<Blog> spacecrafts;
ArrayList<String> post_Key;
ProgressBar progress;
public CustomAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<Blog> spacecrafts,ArrayList<String>post_Key,ProgressBar progressBar) {
    this.c = c;
    this.spacecrafts = spacecrafts;
    this.post_Key=post_Key;
    progress=progressBar;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return spacecrafts.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return spacecrafts.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if(convertView==null)
    {
        convertView= LayoutInflater.from(c).inflate(R.layout.card_view,parent,false);

    }

    final ImageView imageView= (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageId);
    imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85,85));
    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
    final Blog s= (Blog) this.getItem(position);
    final String key=post_Key.get(position);
    progress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    Toast.makeText(c,"Up",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Glide.with(c).load(s.getImage()).thumbnail(0.5f).crossFade().fitCenter().placeholder(R.drawable.fb_avatar).diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL).listener(new RequestListener<String, GlideDrawable>() {
        @Override
        public boolean onException(Exception e, String model,     Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {

            Toast.makeText(c,"error",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onResourceReady(GlideDrawable resource, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFromMemoryCache, boolean isFirstResource) {

            return false;
        }
    }).into(imageView);
    Toast.makeText(c,"Down",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent=new Intent(c,BlogSingleActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("blog_id",key);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            c.startActivity(intent);


        }
    });

    return convertView;
   }


  }

  class FirebaseHelper {

DatabaseReference db;
Boolean saved=null;
ArrayList<Blog> spacecrafts=new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String>postkeys=new ArrayList<>();
FirebaseAuth mAuth;
public FirebaseHelper(DatabaseReference db) {
    this.db = db;
    mAuth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
}

//IMPLEMENT FETCH DATA AND FILL ARRAYLIST

//READ BY HOOKING ONTO DATABASE OPERATION CALLBACKS
public ArrayList<Blog> retrieve() {
    db.orderByChild("uid").equalTo(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid().toString()).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            spacecrafts.clear();
            for(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1:dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                Blog blog=dataSnapshot1.getValue(Blog.class);
                String key=dataSnapshot1.getKey();
                spacecrafts.add(blog);

            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

    return spacecrafts;
}
 public ArrayList<String> fetchKey(){
     db.orderByChild("uid").equalTo(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
         @Override
         public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
             postkeys.clear();
             for(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1:dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                 String key = dataSnapshot1.getKey();
                 postkeys.add(key);
             }
         }

         @Override
         public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

         }
     });
     return postkeys;
 }
  }
```

Comment: Have you tried in real device? as your code seems perfect

Comment: Yes, I have tried it in real device, don't know why this happening

Comment: Did you find the cause of this problem? I'm having a similar issue.